# TypeError: integer argument expected, got float when converting an image to greyscale

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am using the following code to convert a color image to a grayscale image. Why does it throw a `TypeError`?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("Penguins.jpg")
pixel = im.load()
width, height = im.size
for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
        R,G,B = pixel[x,y]
        pixel[x,y] = ((0.299*R+0.587*G+0.114*B),(0.299*R+0.587*G+0.114*B),(0.299*R+0.587*G+0.114*B))

im.save("Penguins_new.jpg")
```

Comment: Have you considered that you are *passing a float and not an integer*?

Comment: I know but how should I do to make it correct?

Comment: Have a look at my answer. It will hopefully solve your solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The argument that you are passing to `pixel[x, y]` needs to be an `int`, not a `float`. Try casting it as an integer.

```
pixel[x, y] = ((int(0.299*R) + int(...
```

Comment: but the question is float ~"~

Comment: That's not a cast; it's a constructor call. Python doesn't have casts.

Comment: You can think of it as a conversion then. And then the same can be said for that python doesn't have constructors either. People use different terminology. Don't start a war, just keep it simple. 

And, also, the reason that you are getting the error, is because the function does not want a float, but rather an integer. So you can't pass a float, you have to pass an integer.

Comment: If I want to pass a float, what function should I use?

Comment: Replace `int` with `float`.

Comment: @Zizouz212 Python has constructors, but not casts. They are not the same thing and the terms are not interchangable. [The documentation on `__init__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__) and other pages in the standard library documentation refer to _constructors._ You can certainly _say_ that Python has casts or that it does not have constructors, but you will be factually incorrect.

Comment: @BlacklightShining Then, I believe you are accusing thousands of people of being *factually incorrect*. Like this article: http://www.peterbe.com/plog/interesting-casting-in-python

Comment: @BlacklightShining Also, that has to do with classes, not types. You should figure out the difference between the two.

Comment: @Zizouz212 I am indeed asserting that however many people have stated or implied that Python has casts are _factually incorrect._ Also, Python does not distinguish classes from types (at least not beginning with Python 3).